# How do you change the HTML code for an icon in Webflow?

Tags: html, referrer, webflow, rel

[image]I'm trying to add `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"` code to a LinkedIn icon on a Webflow website and was wondering how I can edit the HTML code through Webflow?

Another question I have is if the `rel="noopener"` I add needs to be after `target="_blank"` or if it can be before the `href`?

On Webflow I added a custom attribute of `rel="noopener"` to the LinkedIn icon div.
When I uploaded and inspected the website I see that the `rel="noopener"` is before the `href`.

I'm not sure if I did it correctly, and wanted to make sure before I do an SEO scan on HubSpot.

I've included my side view for the div block I'm currently working in.

[image: here is the HTML when I inspect the page after adding rel="noopener"]

Comment: Show your code, screenshot the page? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76458247/edit) your question to include such details. Also I think yeah it's OK, you did it correctly.

Comment: Ah thank you I'm new to overflow. I've included the image above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: See [Does the order of the canonical tag and URL in HTML matter?](https://www.reddit.com/r/TechSEO/comments/m3p07u/does_the_order_of_the_canonical_tag_and_url_in/), so yes it doesn't matter what you put first, also what's your icon *exactly*?

Comment: just the LinkedIn icon

Comment: [From here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ecu.png)

Comment: I believe a div block was used.

Comment: I see that the only to edit HTML/CSS directly is [Custom code embed](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/custom-code-embed) but [Div block](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/div-block) doesn't have such functionality. You should be able to customize that `div`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: currently in the footer of the site we have all of the social media icons in their own div blocks with links that link to their respective sites.

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: Just wanted to know if by adding rel="noreferrer" and having it appear before the link to LinkedIn would get rid of my SEO suggestion, but you said it should be ok so I'll run my scan. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: You're welcome, incase the scan works well, let me know so I can write an answer.